# How is the Longest Path Problem NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard

From the following link:

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~lyuu/complexity/2016/20161129s.pdf

[image]

So basically, in our iff proof, we have to show two directions:

Forward: If Hamiltonian Path has a yes-instance, so does longest path. This makes sense because we can just let "k" = |V| - 1 if hamiltonian path is yes. Then clearly there is a longest simple path with |V| - 1 edges.

I'm having trouble with the backward part

Backward: If Longest Path has a yes instance, so does longest path. Let's assume that there is a longest path from s to t of length k (this can be a different k than the one we defined above?). **How does that guarantee that there is a hamiltonian path from s-t?** If it is the same k, where k = |V| - 1, then I agree there is a hamiltonian path, but what if this k is something different?

Answer (score 2):

> How does that guarantee that there is a hamiltonian path from s-t?

It doesn't, but the Longest Path problem doesn't require a path between particular vertices, it only requires that some simple path of length $K$ exist in the graph.  To reduce Hamiltonian Path to Longest Path you just require that path to have $|V| - 1$ edges, which in a simple path *must* involve all the vertices in the graph, making it a Hamiltonian Path.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that we want to reduce Hamilton path problem to the longest path problem. Hence we have to show that an instance I of Hamilton path problem has a Hamilton path if and only if its transformed instance f(I) has a longest path of length n-1 where f is the reduction. 
We don't have to care about longest path problem instances where k is something different.

To make the point clearer, you could show the correctness of the reduction in a slightly different way:
Show that if G has a Hamilton path, then G has a path of length n - 1.
And if G has *no* Hamilton path, then G has no path of length n - 1.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Kyle Jones; and the *'iff'* part in the proof looks little fishy to me.
For the NP-Hard part, you may refer to my answer here https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/137129/62634 - I've tried to prove it from the basics.

For the 1st part, to prove that the longest path is NP, I was thinking to start off with guessing a path of size K=|V| -1 and then check in polynomial time whether it exists/simple-path. If not, then I guess again a path of size K-1, and do the test, and this goes on until k=1. This way I have to guess only |V|-1 time. By contrast, the proof that you've cited, could also mean that there are exponential number of paths of size between size K and |V|-1.