# How to prove NP-hardness of a Hamiltonian Path problem by reducing longest-path problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, proof-techniques

I know how to prove longest-path problem by reducing Hamiltonian Path problem.

Here I want to prove NP-hardness of a Hamiltonion Path problem by reducing longest-path problem. (pretend we know longest-path problem is NP-hardness, not Hamiltonion Path problem)

I'm wondering if it is possible to reduce Hamiltonian Path problem to longest path problem.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the Longest Path Problem NP complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121265/how-is-the-longest-path-problem-np-complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a graph $G$ of order $n$. $G$ has a simple path of length $\geq n - 1$ if and only if $G$ has a hamiltonian path.

Comment: why it has to be a simple path?

Comment: Because the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is defined only for simple paths.

Comment: @musk If a path is not simple then you can move to and fro on an edge infinite times. The longest path would trivially be infinite.